# MySQL: Display only 200 characters from total value

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a MySQL table with a field named `description`, with a record like this:

> Former cop Brian O'Conner partners with ex-con Dom Toretto on the opposite side of the law.Since Brian and Mia Toretto broke Dom out of custody, they've blown across many borders to elude authorities. Now backed into a corner in Rio de Janeiro, they must pull one last job in order to gain their freedom. As they assemble their elite team of top racers, the unlikely allies know their only shot of getting out for good means confronting the corrupt businessman who wants them dead. But he's not the only one on their tail. Hard-nosed federal agent Luke Hobbs never misses his target. When he is assigned to track down Dom and Brian, he and his strike team launch an all-out assault to capture them. But as his men tear through Brazil, Hobbs learns he can't separate the good guys from the bad.

How can I display first 200 characters of it? Like this:

> Former cop Brian O'Conner partners with ex-con Dom Toretto on the opposite side of the law.Since Brian and Mia Toretto broke Dom out of custody, they've blown across many borders to elude authorities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT LEFT(description, 200)
FROM yourtable
```

relevant docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left).

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(description, 1, 200) 
FROM your_table
```

You can find docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM table ...`

Then in PHP just:

```
echo substr($desc, 0, 200); //1st 200 characters
```

**[DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)**

Comment: hey neal thanks please also answer this question too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979513/mysql-multiple-row-as-comma-separated-single-row-separate-with

Comment: @SumitBijvani you tagged your question [tag:php], i gave you a php relevant answer

Comment: @Neal the third arg is the length not the ending offset. So 200 should be there ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(`description`,1,200) as description FROM table
```

That will start at position 1 and go 200 characters, and return the field as 'description' which is easier for mysql_fetch_assoc()

Comment: Marco, that's incorrect (I just tested it on my db to be sure before posting). also, from the MySQL docs:
For all forms of SUBSTRING(), the position of the first character in the string from which the substring is to be extracted is reckoned as 1.

Answer (score -1):

It is better to get the substring from the database rather than getting the whole string into PHP and then slicing it:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(description, 0, 200) FROM TABLE_NAME
```